# How should I fix it? Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, factorial

I am making the following graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def g(x):
    return np.exp(-10)*pow(10,x)/math.factorial(x)


x=np.linspace(0,100,100)
plt.plot(x,g(x))
plt.show()
```

I have the error when taking the factorial. When running the code it throws me the following error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How should I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think `factorial(100)` is something <del>worth</del> safe computing. Also, `np.linspace(0,100,100)` are not integers, `factorial` might not work.

Comment: I have fixed the error with `from scipy.special import factorial` taking the function as `np.exp(-10)*pow(10,x)/factorial(x)` .  The domain of the function is between (0,40) i.e. `x=np.linspace(0,40)`, the Stirling's Approximation is not necessary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the error with `from scipy.special import factorial`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import factorial

def g(x):
    return np.exp(-10)*pow(10,x)/factorial(x)


x=np.linspace(0,100)
plt.plot(x,g(x))
plt.show()
```

The Stirling's Approximation is not necessary. Thank you.

[image: Distribution]

Answer (score 0):

Math functions can't be called on numpy arrays, only on numpy scalars. To calculate the element-wise factorial of an array, [`scipy.special.factorial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.factorial.html) is needed.

As mentioned in the comments, `np.linspace(0, 100, 100)` aren't integers. You'd need `np.linspace(0, 100, 101)` to get the integers from 0 to 100. As `scipy.special.factorial` falls back on the gamma function, non-integers aren't necessarily a problem. Note, however, that these types of values aren't very precise.

To show your curve, you might want to use a log scale:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.special

def g(x):
    return np.exp(-10) * pow(10, x) / scipy.special.factorial(x)

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
ax1.plot(x, g(x))
ax1.set_title('linear plot')
ax2.plot(x, g(x))
ax2.set_yscale('log')
ax2.set_title('log plot')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]